How to customize a TextField on Jetpack compose
Hello I wan to customize my textfield as you can see on this picture using jetpack compose librairie, but as you know on jetpack compose we just have OutlinedTextField and Textfield how can i do to customize my text field to have this please: enter image description here
Thanks #JetpackCompose, #Kotlink

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can make your own text field:
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.material.TextField
import androidx.compose.material.TextFieldDefaults
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.RectangleShape
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable
fun CustomTextField(
    leadingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    hint: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    shape: Shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
    backgroundColor: Color = Color.White,
    shadowColor: Color = Color.Blue,
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .clip(shape)
            .background(backgroundColor)
            .shadow(
                elevation = 4.dp,
                shape = RectangleShape,
                shadowColor = shadowColor
            )
    ) {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp)
        ) {
            if (leadingIcon != null) {
                leadingIcon()
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
            }
            Text(
                text = hint,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface
            )
        }
    }
}


